# Camel - Configuring multiple component beans in Spring

Tags: apache-camel

In Spring xml you can configure your (say) JMS Endpoint as follows:

```
<bean id="solaceJmsComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mySolaceConnectionFactory/>
</bean>
```

But what if I have another completely unrelated JMS connection that I need running on the same server?  I can add another component bean to the config, eg:

```
<bean id="anotherJmsComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="anotherConnectionFactory/>
</bean>
```

But when I specify a URL (say `jms:queue:foo`) I don't know how to specify which instance of JmsComponent to use.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id of the bean is the name to use in the Camel endpoint, eg use

```
solaceJmsComponent:queue:foo
anotherJmsComponent:queue:bar
```

The `jms` is just the default name.

Comment: Claus!  You're the best.  How you find the time to code and answer SO questions is beyond me.